# Angular 2 - components communication

Tags: angular, input, output, components, communication

I'm new to Angular2 and I'm trying to get my head around `@Input` and `@Output` type thing.

As an example I have two components. I want a button in component one to toggle the visibility of component two.

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'widget-one',
template:'<div class="widget-one" (click)="sendToWidgetTwo()"><button>Send to widget two</button></div>'})

export class WidgetOne {

  constructor(){
    console.log('Hello Widget One');
  }

  sendToWidgetTwo(){
    console.log("button clicked");
    // communicate with widget two
  }

}
```

---

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'widget-two',
  template:'<div *ngIf="showing" class="widget-two">{{msg}}</div>' 
})
export class WidgetTwo {

  msg = "hello widget two";
  showing = true;

  constructor(){
    console.log('Hello Widget Two');
  }

}
```

---

I want WidgetOne's button to toggle WidgetTwo's `showing` variable to show or hide it.

Comment: If the two components are not in a parent-child relationship then one approach is to use a service that they can communicate through. Overall I'd recommend you read this part of the documentation that describes the different options: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both components have a common parent, the first component should emit an event that would set a boolean var in the parent to toggle the visibility of the second component. In the template of the parent use the *ngIf directive bound to this boolean variable to show/hide the component two.
I've recorded a short video to show how to implement inter-component communication using the parent component as a mediator here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSXx4NoKEYY&t=3s

Comment: Thanks! Great video. I'll let you know how I go :)

Comment: If you use Angular CLI, there is no need to do these special arrangements with the Stock interface as was shown in the video.